# Can´t export canvas ti image if i add image from external url fabric js

Tags: image, fabricjs

Hello i create a function to add image from an external URL:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="IMGbyURL" placeholder="http://"/><a href="#" onclick="ImgPorURL(document.getElementById('IMGbyURL').value)">Agregar</a>
```

Javascript to add image:

```
function ImgPorURL(srcImg){     
fabric.Image.fromURL(srcImg, function(oImg) {
canvas.add(oImg);
})
}
```

HTML to export:

```
<a href="#" onclick="convertToImagen()">Export</a>
```

Javascript to export canvas:

```
function convertToImagen() {
canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();  
window.open(canvas.toDataURL('jpg')); 
}
```

But does not work, the funny thing is that if i upload the image, save to any folder in the server and add the image to the canvas, it works perfectly and the canvas is exported as an image, but not work if i add the image from external site... Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

The funny thing, as you call it is called **CORS**.
Cross origin resource sharing.

Fabricjs support some CORS functionality

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(srcImg, function(oImg) {
canvas.add(oImg);
}, {crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'});
```

If this does not work, well the server of the external link does not support sharing images all around. There is little than you can do other than sharing on another server, including your.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @AndreaBogazzi's answer - if the FabricJS config `{crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'}` won't work you can utilise PHP proxying script (on backend) that will download images from 3rd party to your domain and serve fabric with them. Here's the [sample script](http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/image_proxy.php):

```
<?php
// define absolute path to image folder
$image_folder = '/home/mydomain/upload_folder/';
// get the image name from the query string
// and make sure it's not trying to probe your file system
if (isset($_GET['pic']) && basename($_GET['pic']) == $_GET['pic']) {
    $pic = $image_folder.$_GET['pic'];
    if (file_exists($pic) && is_readable($pic)) {
        // get the filename extension
        $ext = substr($pic, -3);
        // set the MIME type
        switch ($ext) {
            case 'jpg':
                $mime = 'image/jpeg';
                break;
            case 'gif':
                $mime = 'image/gif';
                break;
            case 'png':
                $mime = 'image/png';
                break;
            default:
                $mime = false;
        }
        // if a valid MIME type exists, display the image
        // by sending appropriate headers and streaming the file
        if ($mime) {
            header('Content-type: '.$mime);
            header('Content-length: '.filesize($pic));
            $file = @ fopen($pic, 'rb');
            if ($file) {
                fpassthru($file);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```